# SoRayPickAction in Open Inventor?

Tags: c++, 3d, openinventor

Sorry if this is a repeat, but I'm trying to figure out the implementation of SoRayPickAction in Open Inventor. I'm trying to implement it so that it will, when the mouse is clicked, select a particular node so then I can translate, rotate, etc. I have three nodes: desk, lamp, and frame (picture frame). However, I don't think that my code is at all right. I also have various methods such a MouseButtonCallback (which will check if the mouse is clicked and then use a navigator) and MouseMoveCallback (same idea). So here's the code that I have, but do you have any suggestions? Right now, well, it doesn't do anything.

```
SbViewportRegion viewport(400,300); 
    SoRayPickAction m(viewport); 
    m.setRay(SbVec3f(0.0,0.0,0.0), SbVec3f(0.0,0.0,-1.0));
    m.apply(callback_node);
    const SoPickedPoint *mpp = m.getPickedPoint(); 
    if(mpp != NULL) {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    }
```

Might you also know of an action in OpenInventor that can "place" a node in the scene, i.e. place the lamp on top of the desk, frame on the wall, etc. Is it with paths? I don't even know what I'm looking for, unfortunately. Thanks so much for your help!!

Edit: How does this look? 
           SoSeparator *desk2; 
           SoSeparator *lamp2; 
           SoSeparator *pic_frame2; 
           SoSeparator *picked;

```
void MouseButtonCallback(void* data, SoEventCallback* node)
{
   SoHandleEventAction* action = node->getAction();
   const SoMouseButtonEvent* event = static_cast<const SoMouseButtonEvent*>(action-          >getEvent());
   Navigator* nav = static_cast<Navigator*>(data);

   if (SoMouseButtonEvent::isButtonPressEvent(event, event->getButton())) 
       nav->OnMouseDown(event, action);
   else
         nav->OnMouseUp(event, action);

   const SbViewportRegion & viewportRegion = action->getViewportRegion();
   SoRayPickAction pickAction(viewportRegion); 

   SbVec2s mousePos = event->getPosition(viewportRegion); 
   pickAction.setPoint(mousePos); 
   pickAction.setPickAll(TRUE); 
   pickAction.setRadius(2.0F); 
   pickAction.setRay(SbVec3f(0.0,0.0,0.0), SbVec3f(0.0,0.0,-1.0));
   pickAction.apply(node);
   const SoPickedPoint *mpp = pickAction.getPickedPoint(); 
   if(mpp != NULL) {
  SoPath *path = mpp->getPath(); 

 if(desk2 != NULL && path->containsNode(desk2))
  {             //but this doesn't respond with cout when I try to test it :(
      if (SoMouseButtonEvent::isButtonPressEvent(event, event->getButton()))
      *picked = *desk2; 
  }
  else if(lamp2 != NULL && path->containsNode(lamp2))
  {
      if (SoMouseButtonEvent::isButtonPressEvent(event, event->getButton()))
      *picked = *lamp2;
  }
  else if(pic_frame2 != NULL && path->containsNode(pic_frame2))
  {
      if (SoMouseButtonEvent::isButtonPressEvent(event, event->getButton())) 
      *picked = *pic_frame2;
  }

           action->setHandled();
   }
 void MouseMoveCallback(void* data, SoEventCallback* node)
{
    SoHandleEventAction* action = node->getAction();
    const SoLocation2Event* event = static_cast<const SoLocation2Event*>(action->getEvent());
    Navigator* nav = static_cast<Navigator*>(data);

    nav->OnMouseMove(event, action);

     const SbViewportRegion & viewportRegion = action->getViewportRegion();
    SoRayPickAction pickAction(viewportRegion); 

    SbVec2s mousePos = event->getPosition(viewportRegion); 
    pickAction.setPoint(mousePos); 
    pickAction.setPickAll(TRUE); 
    pickAction.setRadius(2.0F); 
    pickAction.setRay(SbVec3f(0.0,0.0,0.0), SbVec3f(0.0,0.0,-1.0));
    pickAction.apply(node);
    const SoPickedPoint *mpp = pickAction.getPickedPoint(); 
    if(mpp != NULL) {
  SoPath *path = mpp->getPath(); 
  if(desk2 != NULL && path->containsNode(desk2))
  {
      *picked = *desk2; //can't remember how to set pointers, will figure that out
  }
  else if(lamp2 != NULL && path->containsNode(lamp2))
  {
      *picked = *lamp2;
  }
  else if(pic_frame2 != NULL && path->containsNode(pic_frame2))
  {
       *picked = *pic_frame2;
  }
   }  
        action->setHandled();
    }

  (part of main method) 

 //desk 
SoTransform *desk_transform = new SoTransform; 
desk_transform->translation.setValue(SbVec3f(380,340,330)); 
SoSeparator* desk2 = new SoSeparator(); 
desk2->addChild(desk_transform);
desk2->addChild(desk); 
root->addChild(desk2);

  SoTransformerManip* picked_transform = new SoTransformerManip(); 
   picked_transform->translation.setValue(SbVec3f(200,340,330));
  SoSeparator* pick2 = new SoSeparator(); 
  pick2->addChild(picked_transform); 
  pick2->addChild(picked); 
  root->addChild(pick2); 

 std::auto_ptr<btCollisionShape> picked_shape(new btBoxShape(btVector3(10.0f, 10.0f,  10.0f)));
  CollisionEngine* picked_collision = new CollisionEngine(collision_world.get(),      picked_shape.get());
  picked_collision->translation_in.connectFrom(&picked_transform->translation);
  picked_collision->rotation_in.connectFrom(&picked_transform->rotation);
  picked_transform->translation.connectFrom(&picked_collision->translation_out);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the picked point. You then get an `SoPath` as you guessed.  Then see if the path contains a node you want to do something with.

```
SbViewportRegion viewport(400,300); 
    SoRayPickAction m(viewport); 
    m.setRay(SbVec3f(0.0,0.0,0.0), SbVec3f(0.0,0.0,-1.0));
    m.apply(callback_node);
    const SoPickedPoint *mpp = m.getPickedPoint(); 
    if(mpp != NULL) {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
        SoPath * path = pickedPoint->getPath();

        if (deskSeparator != NULL && path->containsNode(deskSeparator)
        {
        }
        else if (lampSeparator != NULL && path->containsNode(lampSeparator)
        {
        }
        else if (radomeSeparator != NULL && path->containsNode(radomeSeparator)
        {
            if (    SoMouseButtonEvent::isButtonPressEvent( event, SoMouseButtonEvent::BUTTON2 )
                 || ( SoMouseButtonEvent::isButtonPressEvent( event, SoMouseButtonEvent::BUTTON1 ) && event->wasShiftDown() ) )
            {
                modelPointMoving = true;
                const SoDetail * detail = modelPickedPoint->getDetail( 0 );
                int face = -1;
                if ( detail && detail->isOfType( SoFaceDetail::getClassTypeId() ) )
                {
                    const SoFaceDetail * faceDetail = static_cast<const SoFaceDetail *>( detail );
                    face = faceDetail->getFaceIndex();
                }
                updateStatusBar( face, point.getValue(), normal.getValue() );
                graphicModel.postNote( pickedPoint );
                break;
            }
            else if ( SoMouseButtonEvent::isButtonPressEvent( event, SoMouseButtonEvent::BUTTON1 ) )
            {
            }
            else if ( SoMouseButtonEvent::isButtonReleaseEvent( event, SoMouseButtonEvent::BUTTON1 ) )
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

You'll eventually want to connect the pick ray to the mouse position sort of like this:

```
//  Set an 2-pixel wide region around the pixel.
SbVec2s mousePosition = event->getPosition( viewportRegion );
pickAction.setPoint( mousePosition );
pickAction.setPickAll( TRUE );
pickAction.setRadius( 2.0F );
```

This is done before you `.apply()` the pick action of course.

I guess my code is a mixture of yours and mine but I think it should give you a start.  Also, this is sitting inside a function to process mouse events:

```
void
RenderWindow::mouseEvent( void *, SoEventCallback * eventCallback )
{
    const SoEvent *event = eventCallback->getEvent();

    if ( ! event )
    {
        qDebug() << "  **  Error in mousePressCallback: Event not found.";
        return;
    }

    //SoType eventType = event->getTypeId();   
    //SbName eventTypeName = eventType.getName();
    //const char * eventTypeString = eventTypeName.getString();
    SoHandleEventAction * action = eventCallback->getAction();
    const SbViewportRegion & viewportRegion = action->getViewportRegion();
    SoRayPickAction pickAction( viewportRegion );
```

Up in main or a setup routine I register the mouse event (for both click action and location (moving the mouse over the viewport):

```
//  Add a mouse event callback to catch mouse button presses.
SoEventCallback * mouseEventCallback = new SoEventCallback();
mouseEventCallback->setName( "MOUSE_EVENT_CALLBACK" );
mouseEventCallback->addEventCallback( SoMouseButtonEvent::getClassTypeId(), &::mouseEvent, static_cast<void *>( this ) );
//  Add a mouse event callback to catch mouse motion.
mouseEventCallback->addEventCallback( SoLocation2Event::getClassTypeId(), &::mouseEvent, static_cast<void *>( this ) );
rootSeparator->addChild( mouseEventCallback );
```

Now that I look at it I wrote the chunks in reverse order ;-).  Sorry.

Good Luck

Comment: Great, wow, thanks so much, emsr!! Your code makes a ton of sense now. Sorry, what is "radomeSeparator?" And does this code change if I realized that unfortunately, desk, lamp, and frame are Separators rather than nodes? Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, radomeSeparator is from my code ;-)  I work with aircraft.  I forgot to change it to look like your code.  Obviously, you'll want to use your own separators.  Also, a SoSeparator is a SoNode - i.e. SoSeparator inherits from SoNode (via SoGroup and maybe something else).  SoNode is the parent of a *lot* of things in Inventor so you could pick an SoMaterial, SoTransform or whatever.

Comment: I'm sorry, so I'm a bit lost. I seriously hate local variables! I already have MouseMoveCallback and MouseButtonCallback methods. However, how do you think I can possibly connect all three of these to  a RayPickAction? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Inside both your callbacks you will 1. Create a RayPickAction from the screen coordinate, 2. apply the pick action and get the PickedPoint and from that get the Path, 3. See which of your objects (Separators) got picked using containsNode on you stored object separators, 4. Maybe save the picked Separator in a pointer somewhere where it wont get lost if the action is SoMouseButtonEvent::isButtonPressEvent, 5. For the picked separator find the Transform node and update it as you move the mouse, 6. When isButtonReleaseEvent clear the picked separator variable.

Comment: Maybe post a larger sample of what you're working on - if not the whole thing?